# how can I recall a part of body in a method that would call after each second?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nstimer

I am coding as follows

```
-(void) moveMethod :(Paddle *) pad {
    float counter = 10;
    self.position = CGPointMake(80,counter);
}
```

Now I want increase counter with +5 after each one second, what should I do, so that object should move upside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below by declaring **counter** as **static** variable.

```
-(void) moveMethod :(id) sender {
    static float counter = 10;
    self.position = CGPointMake(80,counter);
    counter+=5;
}
```

Here is the timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
    target:self
    selector:@selector(moveMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

Comment: but move method is taking CCSprite objects again and again, then what be solution?